# How to fix"some widgets in a relativelayout of android does not appear"

Tags: java, android, layout, show

I write a `relativeLayout` with some widgets ,why just the widget notebook appears, the `linearLayout` **btn_list**  and the button scale donnot appear?How to let them appear?

The code shows below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/title"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="38dp">
 <Button
 android:layout_width="15dp"
 android:layout_height="15dp"/>     
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_below="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/black">
 <com.dazzle.note.view.**NoteBook**//surfaceview defined by myself
   android:id="@+id/note_book"
   android:layout_below="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<**LinearLayout**
   android:id="@+id/btn_list"
   android:layout_width="33dp"
   android:layout_height="155dp"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/title" >   
  <Button
   android:id="@+id/pen"
   android:layout_width="21dp"
   android:layout_height="21dp"/>
  <Button  .../>
</LinearLayout>
 <**Button**
   android:id="@+id/scale2"
   android:layout_width="20dp"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_gravity="end"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: structured question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your btn_list below your notebook not below the title -

```
...
<**LinearLayout**
  android:id="@+id/btn_list"
  android:layout_width="33dp"
  android:layout_height="155dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/note_book" > 
  ...
```

Or you can make your parent view to LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.